# React using an inline style how do I the color of "item.email" to the CSS color text-red-600 if the content of "item.email" includes a space?

Tags: reactjs, indexof, inline-styles

I need to change the color of "item.email" to the CSS color text-red-600 if the content of "item.email" includes a space.

```
          <div className="relative text-sm w-64 left-400 style={{item.email}.indexOf(' ') = -1 ? text-gray-600 : text-red-600 }">
        {item.email}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as simple as

```
<div className={`relative text-sm w-64 left-400 
${item.email.indexOf(' ') === -1 ? 'text-gray-600' : 'text-red-600'}`}></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the template string throws an error. Even after I fixed the missing backtick.  But I see that I was missing the '==='.

Comment: What was the error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors.  The answer is to put the style outside of the className.  For example:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).